# AJAX Password Change without Refresh

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery, passwords

I'm trying to implement password change functionality into my website. I've got all the password changing script, validation, etc done. But now I need to prevent the page from going to the script page or refreshing. When the user clicks the submit button, I want nothing to change except a message displaying `successfully changed` or `error`. So here's my html:

```
<form id="change_Pass" action="" method="post">
    Current Password<input type="password" id="change_password" name="change_password"><br>
    New Password<input type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password"><br>
    Verify Password<input type="password" id="verify_password" name="verify_password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="change_pass_submit">
</form>
```

And my jquery:

```
$('#change_pass_submit').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);  
    $.ajax({
        data: $this.serialize(), // get the form data
        type: "POST", // GET or POST
        url: "/Private/change_password.php", // the file to call
        success: function() { // on success..
            //$('#success_div).html(response); // update the DIV
            alert("good");
        },
        error: function() { // on error..
            //$('#error_div).html(e); // update the DIV
            alert("bad");
        }
    });
    return false; //so it doesn't refresh when submitting the page
});
```

And my php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../classes/Bcrypt.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$usr = $_SESSION["username"];
$old_pwd = $_POST["change_password"];
$new_pwd = $_POST["new_password"];
$new_pwd = Bcrypt::hash($new_pwd);
try {
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host=*;dbname=*;charset=UTF-8','*','*');
    $query = "SELECT *
            FROM Conference
            WHERE Username = :un";

    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(':un', $usr);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $hash = $row[0]["Password"];
    $is_correct = Bcrypt::check($old_pwd, $hash);
    if($is_correct) {
        $query = "UPDATE Conference
                SET `Password`=:new_pwd 
                WHERE Username = :usr";

        $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':new_pwd', $new_pwd);
        $stmt->bindParam(':usr', $usr);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    } else return false;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

But for some reason, when I hit the submit button, the page STILL goes to `change_password.php`. I have no idea why, i've looked at so many tutorials and my code matches theirs but for some reason mine won't stay on the same page. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You should have check the js console to see if there's any error. None the less, your code already has error. You are passing variable inside the function without putting them as parameters in both the success and error event.

Comment: @Richard try debugging on firefox. Use firebug extension if you already haven't. Net tab on firebug console shows requests. You may identify whether your problem is in js or php then correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your handler to the form's `submit` event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#change_Pass', function() {
    var $this = $(this);  
    $.ajax({
        data: $this.serialize(), // get the form data
        type: "POST", // GET or POST
        url: "/Private/change_password.php", // the file to call
        success: function() { // on success..
            //$('#success_div).html(response); // update the DIV
            alert("good");
        },
        error: function() { // on error..
            //$('#error_div).html(e); // update the DIV
            alert("bad");
        }
    });

    return false; //so it doesn't refresh when submitting the page
});
```

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't work. It doesn't change the password nor does it stay on the same page.

Comment: Yah I just checked, there's nothing there. Completely empty.

Comment: Do you get any alert messages at all? Is this code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` callback?

Comment: i get no alerts and every jquery i write is always in `.ready()`

Comment: Odd. Is this submit form being dynamically generated by any chance?

Comment: well it is hidden at all times unless the user logins in and clicks the settings button. Then it appears in one of the tabs of a content slider. Let me try to find the content slider online. Edit: [Here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/28/pretty-simple-content-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/) it is

Comment: Would you happen to have a live demo of this page?

Comment: sure gimme a second to work get up and running. Also, I found out that `$('#change_Pass').submit(function(){` isn't even being triggered, i put an alert on the top and it didn't fire so the content slider is interfering somehow. Let me get that demo first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18354/discussion-between-richard-and-blender)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$('#change_pass_submit').click(function()`, use `$('#change_Pass').submit(function()`.

.click will only work if the submit button is actually clicked where .submit will work even if the user presses enter.

This should fix your error but it is untested.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting preventDefault(); in the last line of the function performed by .submit

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#cambiar_pass_form" ).submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    ...
                    ...
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```